# How to upgrade from Delphi 2007 to XE2?

Tags: delphi, upgrade, delphi-2007, delphi-xe2

We currently use D2007 but are considering an upgrade to XE2. I can think of two "bigger" issues here - the Unicode step from 2007 to 2009 and the whole platform stuff from XE to XE2 (32/64 bit, VCL/Firemonkey with pointer sizes, unit namespacing and whatnot).

AFAIK we also get D2009, D2010 and XE if we buy XE2, so my idea was to tackle the upgrade in two steps:

1. First deal with Unicode. I guess the best way to do this is to upgrade to XE: We would have working generics etc. but no additional issues compared to an upgrade 2007->2009.
2. If step 1 is done and has shown that it works for our customers do XE->XE2.

What do you think? Should we do the whole upgrade in one step instead ? Or two steps but with a different intermediate version?

**Edit:** I'm aware that XE2 doesn't force us to go cross-platform (FireMonkey probably never will be an option for us). I just want to avoid related issues like ["XE2 values of mrAll, mrNoToAll, mrYesToAll and mrClose"](http://www.bobswart.nl/Weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:5029) while fighting any Unicode related problems. And unit namespacing sounds like quite a hindrance if we were to make our units compatible with both D2007 and XE2 during the transition (or is that a bad idea anyway?).

Comment: I cannot restrain myself from thinking "@Nick Hodges would say 'Since you secured everything in your application with automated tests nothing can go wrong and you should jump straight to XE2'"

Comment: That wouldn't describe our situation **exactly**. :-)

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht I'm quite sure Nick would never say that. Just because your unit tests pass, it doesn't mean the program works. How do you test your unit tests?

Comment: Namespacing is not an issue. You can use aliases to ensure your old code still works. By default that will be arranged for you. You have to choose your poison. Yes you can be hit by the ModalResult bug, but what about the bugs that exist in XE and are fixed in XE2?

Comment: @David: I've read somewhere that using the namespacing aliasing slows down the compiler considerably. Do you have any experience there?

Comment: @David I was not _that_ serious. I just got a certain impression following him on T.

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht It's an interesting point. I follow Nick too on Twitter. The point he always misses, in my view, is that having unit tests is no good if your tests are no good. I think Nick's post appear to  trivialises it a little, although of course Twitter rather leads you that way!

Comment: @Ulrich I'm using namespace aliasing on my recently ported project. Around 800kloc, compiles just the same speed as it did with D6 and D2010. I've been impressed with XE2 so far. Obviously there are some teething troubles but nothing too concerning for me. Update 2 fixed the nasty COM bug I was afflicted by.

Comment: @David It's good to have advocates for unit testing, but sometimes I don't like the attitude. And to support your point: http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2011/10/ddt.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just jump straight to XE2. Just because it supports 64-bit and FireMonkey does not mean you have to use them right away.  Just write 32-bit code first and do your Unicode updates as needed, but be mindful of 64-bit when dealing with pointers, memory usage, etc to minimize the need for future migrations when you are ready to tackle 64-bit.  Don't even worry about FireMonkey, as that is a completely new framework, so you would be starting from scratch anyway when you make that jump.

Comment: +1 I seconds this. Go straight to XE2 but only tackle the Unicode port first. Stick to VCL and 32 bit. Change one thing at a time. The only possible concern is that 3rd party vendors may not have full XE2 support by now but I think they are mostly there by now.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I edited my post to (hopefully :-)) clarify my concerns.